# Is PySpark dataframe generated based on LIMIT n spark.sql voltile?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Just curious on one observation I had. I am not an expert on PySpprk. Recently, I was testing out things in one project. I generated a dataframe based on the following code on AWS EMR.

```
qry = '''(select * from `proj-glue-db`.monthly_usage limit 2)'''
df = spark.sql(qry)
```

Then I ran `df.show(5)` several times with a few minutes in between. I noticed that the dataframe content are not consistent. Different set of two rows might be shown. it gives me the impression that the dataframe `df` is not a definitive object. It seems it still links to the original query and may be refreshed somehow. I don't have enough understanding on how Spark works. Is this expected? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, This is expected.. You can check `df.explain(true)` output.